# Horizontalscrollview with ImageButton's

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am using this example: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html to implement a horizontalscrollview "gallery" except I am using imagebuttons instead of an imageview. I have 3 horizontalscrollview's on my screen, I want the user to be able to select an image from each scrollview and when a button is pressed to send the selected images to a new activity. If anything I really want to know how to get the selected images from each scroll view to a new activity. How to realize what the user has selected and get it in another activity? I am new the android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an onClick Listener on the View you are adding in the method called "insertPhoto". And also set the Tag of the View as it's File Path.

So when the view is clicked, you will know which view is clicked and you can checked the Tag of the view from here to get the File Path.

**EDIT :**

```
View insertPhoto(String path){

     Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(path, 220, 220);

     LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
     layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(250, 250));
     layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
     imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(220, 220));
     imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

     layout.addView(imageView);

     layout.setTag(path);
     layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String filePath = (String) v.getTag();
        }
    });

     return layout;
 }


/**
 * Starts YourActivity Activity.
 * 
 * @param context   Activity Context.
 * @param filePath  URI of the File to be uploaded.
 */
public static void startPrinterActivity(Context context, String filePath) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("file_path", filePath);
    context.startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Comment: How can I add the file path of the selected by tagging the view, I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify please?

Comment: See my edit. I added the necessary lines into the method I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! How can I use what is provided from the onClick to put on a button that will start a new activity with the images on them?

Comment: see my edit. I added the method you can run another activity. And If you think that answer was the correct one, please "Accept it as Answer" and Vote it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

all you want is here [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sTH5w/47/),

and original usage is **[here](http://www.google.com/nexus/5/)**

some parts of code.......

```
// bring DOWN
if($(document).scrollTop() - containerTop > 100) {
    if($('#img2').css("margin-top") == "295px") {
        $('#img2').animate({"margin-top": "0px"}, 600);
    }
}  

  // bring UP
if($(document).scrollTop() - containerTop < 100) {
    if($('#img2').css("margin-top") == "0px") {
        $('#img2').animate({"margin-top": "295px"}, 600);
    }
}
```